# interrupt flag vs interrupt pending bit stm32

Tags: c, std, stm32

I'm using the `std` library. I don't know what the difference between `I2C_FLAG_TXE` and `I2C_IT_TXE` is.

Why when in interrupt function we don't use `I2C_ClearFlag` instead `I2C_ClearITPendingBit`? When do we used `I2C_ClearFlag`?

I'm starting learn `stm32f4`. I have very little experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm using the std library. I don't know what the difference between
>   I2C_FLAG_TXE and I2C_IT_TXE is.

From the processor point of view - the interrupt flag which has to be cleared by interrupt routine is set when the processor enters the interrupt.

Interrupt pending flag - indicates that the event which triggers the interrupt occurred but for some reason the interrupt routine has not been invoked yet.

It is good to know your hardware before using any libraries.